# Call an Excel Macro with Variable file name

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I know to run a macro in a module from vbscript it's as simple as

```
objexcel.Application.Run "Filename!MacroName"
```

But, what if the file name is variable--but the directory only contains one file (which has already been opened)?

Could it be as simple as:

```
objexcel.Application.Run wkbk.path "Macroname"
```

Comment: Try `wkbk.path & "!Macroname"`

Answer (score 1):

It works with

```
objexcel.run "MacroName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `wkbk` is a workbook object, you can use:

```
objexcel.Application.Run "'" & wkbk.Name & "'!Macroname"
```

the single quotes are there in case the workbook name contains spaces. Note you don't need the path since the workbook is open.